# .... Is not public in domain; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a simple button that creates a new contact when clicked. I know this error occurs due to public vs. private declaration but I cannot figure out where this is happening. I have already imported the class that houses contact but I am stuck.

```
import java.util.*;


 class Contact {

 private List<Contact> contacts = new LinkedList<Contact>();
private int nextId = 0;

public Contact add(Contact contact) {
    contact.setId(++nextId);
    contacts.add(contact);
    return contact;
}
private String firstName = "";
private String lastName = "";
private String email = "";
```

Here is the code calling contact

```
import domain.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MainUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private Account account = null;

public void setAccount(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
}


 Contact contact = new Contact(); // Error is here
    contact.setFirstname(firstNameFld.getText());
    contact.setLastname(lastNameFld.getText());
    contact.setEmail(emailFld.getText());
    contact.setPhone(phoneFld.getText());

    boolean isValid = contact.validate();
    if(!isValid) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "All fields are required for a Contact", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Your new Contact has been saved", "Saved Contact", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    firstNameFld.setText("");
    lastNameFld.setText("");
    emailFld.setText("");
    phoneFld.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Your `class Contact` is not `public`.

Comment: You should write `public class Contact {`

Answer (score 0):

Your contact class is package private, change it to public or move the class to the same package.